# Debugging Touch Events on mobile.

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, webkit, sitefinity-5

The situation.

I have a site that has a menu strip with some links. On a desktop these links work as expected, on mobile firefox, great! However on webkit, safari and chrome, they don't seem to register when you touch them.

I used Adobe Edge to check it out, but it worked fine in that browser, which browser is that anyways, is that webkit based or other?

I also tried using js to debug, but no luck. I would try to to get an `alert()` if say the parent element, or the link element itself was touched, I  can only seem to get them to register if I mash around a bit.

The site is built on Sitefinity, I have looked around and can't seem to find anything relating to this.

How might I be able to go about trying to figure out what the issue is here? It seems to me to be webkit related, correct me if I a wrong, as it happens on chrome and safari.

Answer (score 1):

On Android devices, you can write messages via `console.log('blah!')` and read them using logcat. You shuold also see other javascript errors in there.

See:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: I ended up installing the SDK, and jsut came up with a work around, there was no real solution for what was going on. Seems it was just an odd error. Thanks though!